# mysql innodb space x did not exist in memory

Tags: mysql, innodb

Into my innodb log I got the errors below. How to fix? 
What did it mean? Some tables are corrupted but not all.

```
InnoDB: space id 1753 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_attribute,
InnoDB: space id 1777 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/catalog_eav_attribute,
InnoDB: space id 1626 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/catalog_category_entity_int,
InnoDB: space id 1609 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/catalog_category_entity_text,
InnoDB: space id 1610 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/catalog_category_entity_varchar,
InnoDB: space id 1611 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/customer_eav_attribute,
InnoDB: space id 1746 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/customer_eav_attribute_website,
InnoDB: space id 1747 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/customer_form_attribute,
InnoDB: space id 1754 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_attribute_label,
InnoDB: space id 1779 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_attribute_option,
InnoDB: space id 1780 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_attribute_option_value,
InnoDB: space id 1781 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_entity_attribute,
InnoDB: space id 1784 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_form_element,
InnoDB: space id 1792 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/googleshopping_attributes,
InnoDB: space id 1804 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/salesrule_product_attribute,
InnoDB: space id 1516 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/googlebase_attributes,
InnoDB: space id 1798 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
130906 16:31:27  InnoDB: error: space object of table test_magento/eav_attribute_set,
```

Comment: Was there an unexpected shutdown or crash in the logs prior to these? ...and/or after?

Answer (score 3):

These messages appear to occur when InnoDB hasn't cached a "tablespace object," for a table, which from what I can tell is an internal structure containing the information about the tablespace (.ibd) file for a table.  Under normal conditions all of these would be cached at server startup (and new ones added when tables are created).

So, this suggests you've got data dictionary issues (corruption in `ibdata1`?) but the message does not, itself, appear to be a fatal one.

The message comes from `dict_load_table()` inside `innobase/dict/dict0load.c`, in response to a `FALSE` returned from a call to `fil_space_for_table_exists_in_mem()` in `innobase/include/fil0fil.h`.

Comments there:

```
/*Returns TRUE if a matching tablespace exists in the InnoDB tablespace memory
cache. Note that if we have not done a crash recovery at the database startup,
there may be many tablespaces which are not yet in the memory cache.
@return TRUE if a matching tablespace exists in the memory cache */
```

This suggests that those messages, while not normal under typical operating conditions, are not entirely unexpected if your server is in the middle of InnoDB crash recovery.

The next thing that happens is that InnoDB tries to open the tablespace files, and since there are no messages in your log indicating that this next step isn't succeeding, it seems safe to conclude that the tablespace (ibd) files are at least accessible and the problem will be elsewhere.

All of this suggests that there will have been previous messages and later messages in the log that will give a better indication of the nature of the problem.